# Time service / monkey test

Tags: malware

I have "Vonino onyx QS" tablet and "Monkey test , Time service , Guard service" are always open . How uninstal this?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the complete malware, you have to root your phone, as it needs to hectic tools to remove.

By XDA Forums :

- Root your Tablet with root app, or by using Root Software, the complete guide is here: **[Root your Phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)**

[Note: USB DEBUGGING MUST BE ENABLED Turn on Usb Debugging by going to settings> developer options> Usb debugging]

- Turn off wifi/3G/4G, and then go to settings> apps> all> disable time service and monkey test. (If already frozen via titanium backup or other app) skip this.
- Open Root explorer go to system/xbin and see if there is any file starting with a dot (eg: .ext.base) also note that every (.) file has diff permission then the rest of other files. So just remember those files with dots because those are the one that you're going to remove in terminal emulator.
- Go back to system and then go to Priv-app folder and look for these two files 
  [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) cameraupdate.apk [2] providerCertificate.apk and also notice permission of these two files are different then the rest of Apks so these two are the base of MT TS virus and needs to be deleted.
- Open Terminal Emulator OR if you have access to your device via adb from a computer.
- **WHAT TO TYPE IN TERMINAL EMULATOR or ADB (CMD Windows)**

> ```
> adb devices (Type this line if you're using adb Windows)
> adb shell
> su 
> mount -o remount,rw /system
> cd system/priv-app
> chattr -iaA providerCertificate.apk
> rm providerCertificate.apk
> chattr -aA cameraupdate.apk
> rm cameraupdate.apk
> cd ..
> cd system/xbin
> chattr -iaA .b 
> rm .b
> chattr -iaA .ext.base
> rm .ext.base
> chattr -iaA .sys.apk
> rm .sys.apk
> ```

[NOTE: If you are using older version than KK you need not to type priv-app just type cd system/app]

- Please make sure you type the file name correctly just as providerCertificate C is capital otherwise permission wont change.
- Exit Emulator/ADB

**Taken Source :**

1) http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/fix-monkey-test-time-service-virus-t3194907

2) https://akshatshibu.wordpress.com/earn-easy-money-by-sharing-links-on-the-internet/how-to-remove-monkeytest-%EF%BC%88ghost-push%EF%BC%89malware/